# Commitment and Invitations

Tags: support, site-promotion, user-interface, beta-phase

Couple of questions regarding administrivia.

1. Where/How can I view my commitment criteria for this beta?  What are the requirements to meet it?
2. I swear I have seen a "Know someone that can answer this question" link before but for the life of me I cannot find it...want to forward a question to someone on another SE site.  I seem to recall clicking a link and dropping in an email address from somewhere.

Comment: 2. is right before the "Your Answer" block, and only on the main site. If it's a meta question, you'll have to use the **share** post tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you're talking about fulfilling an Area 51 commitment to this site, which from looking at your [A51 profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/101654/) seems to be the case, this is the wording of the commitment:

   > I commit to participate actively in `<sitename>` for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions.

   From looking at your [main profile](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/259/james), you fulfilled the 'ask or answer at least ten questions' part. Your commitment should be considered met soon after that, and indeed it is now marked as fulfilled.

   Note that the criteria are approximate and the details are deliberately kept secret — posting 10 answers that are deleted as spam won't validate your commitment, and conversely your commitment can be fulfilled with fewer posts. In your case, 10 posts seems to have been what it took.
2. It only shows up on unanswered questions on the main site:

   [image]

   If you want to share answered questions or meta questions (please do!), use the share link:

   [image]

   This one has no “email” button, but you can just take the URL from the share button and use it in an email however you want.

Comment: I should have been more precise, is the email option available when a question already has an answer(s) but none accepted?

Comment: The yellow share box isn't displayed in that case, but you can just take the URL from the share button and use it in an email however you want.

Comment: I was looking for a way that the SR site would send the email, this is not someone I know personally, just incidentally from another site on the network, didnt want to send a link using personal email.

Comment: Ah, the email link on the yellow box actually just directs you to your built-in email client - the SR site doesn't actually send the email. That's not a bad idea, though.